# Typescript - specify "key" type where Object[key of Object] MUST return string[]

Tags: typescript

I need a Type that refers to a specific property on an object which is a `string[]`.

```
interface Example {
  hello: number;
  world: string;
  target: string[];
}

const e: Example = {
  hello: 0, world: 1, target: ['this', 'is', 'annoying']
};

function join<O>(value: string[] | O, key?: keyof O): string {
  // value[key] is invalid because Typescript can't infer that value[key] is string[].
  const toJoin: string[] = Array.isArray(value) ? value : value[key];
  return value.join(',');
}

const csv: string = join<Example>(e, 'target'); // 'this,is,annoying'
```

What Type does "key" need to be in order to infer that it HAS TO be `target` and CANNOT be `world` or `hello`?

If it's possible without using `unknown` or `any` anywhere, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of errors in it, however I think this is what you're looking for:

```
interface Example {
    hello: number;
    world: string;
    target: string[];
    target2: string[]
}

const e: Example = {
    hello: 0, world: "1", target: ['this', 'is', 'annoying'], target2: []
};

// Get a union of the keys of BaseType  whose values are assignable to ValueType
// e.g. PickTypes<Example, string[]> => "target" | "target2"
type PickTypes<BaseType, ValueType> = {
    [Prop in keyof BaseType]: BaseType[Prop] extends ValueType ? Prop : never;
}[keyof BaseType];

function join<O>(value: string[] | O, key: PickTypes<O, string[]>): string {
    const toJoin: string[] = Array.isArray(value) ? value : value[key] as unknown as string[];
    return toJoin.join(',');
}

const csv: string = join<Example>(e, 'target2'); // 'this,is,annoying'
```

It does need casting as typescript is too stupid, but it's 100% typesafe.

Comment: I wish it didn't need the unknown cast, but yes it is type safe and IntelliSense does suggest `target` or `target2` when trying to auto-fill the function execution. Thanks!